# QGIS Clipped Fields

Tags: qgis

I have clipped out a coverage area for some services in QGIS that we cover.  I need to somehow get the UACE10 and UATYPE values out of another shapefile and I can't seem to get these merged.  Basically for the clipped data I have I want to get those data points inserted into my attribute table where the coverage overlaps with the other file.

I've tried Joins and Unions and I can't seem to get it to work.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I should note the original shapefiles were polygons if that makes a difference.  I did check to make sure my projections were the same prior to clipping as well.

Comment: Try the **Intersect** tool. I think there are some existing answers on this site regarding transferring attributes in your case.

Comment: Do you want to merge attributes from a point layer to a (clipped) polygon layer? It would mean a `Join Attributes by Location`. (It is in Vector | Data Management Tools).